# Journey Builder API Event Data Extension does not have email attribute. Can I still send email if its linked to other DE in Data designer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder

In journey builder I am using  API event (as entry source). Whenever the event occurs the Orders DE gets populated that has 2 fields : customer_ID & order_id
and then this Orders DE enters into the journey.
I have linked Orders DE with Customer DE in Data Designer by creating an attribute group.

My question is how can I send emails in the journey if Orders DE does not have email attribute? Can the journey take the email attribute from Customer DE if its linked in Data Designer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `CustomerId` as the subscriber key relation on the Orders DE. You can link this DE to the contact using Data Designer. On the journey use the below setting to send the email to the address on the `'Customer DE'`.

[image]